# How to format incoming email text for HTML display

Tags: php, email, character-encoding

I've set up a script that processes incoming emails and creates blog entries on Blogger. I'm using PEAR's Mail_Mime libs (for now) to read the incoming message. The messages often have characters in them that cannot be read by browsers--this happens most often when people use Outlook or cut/paste from MS Word.

So the output at the other end is something like this:

> Here is a test post with “quotes” and ‘apostrophes�for what it�s worth, it also has dashes�and other strange formatting cut and paste from MS Word.

You can also [see the output](http://testsaas.blogspot.com/2010/07/new-contest-1.html) in the wild.

It's not hard to fix any specific instance, but each client (hotmail, gmail, outlook, etc) seems to handle things just a bit differently. Mail_Mime only seems to munge the output and, if I turn off Mail_Mime's parsing and try to translate the encoded characters myself using mb_convert_encoding or some manual simulation of this, it's even worse.

Please not that this is not going to be solved by selecting the right encoding type and using decode/encode/convert functions. The incoming formats vary from Windows-1252 to UTF8 to just about anything else mail clients can think of.

Has anyone scripted this before that could save me some time by offering up a sample or advice on the best approach? I've tried all the simple answers and done plenty of experimenting, so please don't bother responding unless you've dealt with a similar issue successfully or have a deep understanding of encoding issues.

Comment: The e-mail message has to be interpreted as specified in the header (see *charset* parameter in *Content-Type* field). If it’s missing, RFC 5322 implies US-ASCII.

Comment: This is done automatically by Mail_Mime. THe problem is much more complex than simply understanding the protocol.

Comment: This post has some interesting thoughts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686515/problem-with-character-encoding-on-email-sent-via-php

I couldn't figure out how it could apply to my problem, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, and get my message into valid UTF-8 that is readable from a browser, I found this PHP lib, [ConvertCharset by Mikolaj Jedrzejak](http://mikolajj.republika.pl), which worked on almost everything. It still had issues with a specific symbol (=A0) when converting from Windows-1252 or iso-8859-1. So I converted this character manually before setting the code loose.

Here's what it looks like overall:

```
// decode using Mail_Mime
require 'Mail.php';
require 'Mail/mime.php';
require 'Mail/mimeDecode.php';
$params['include_bodies'] = true;
$params['decode_bodies']  = true; // this decodes it!
$params['decode_headers'] = true;
$decoder = new Mail_mimeDecode($input);
$mime = $decoder->decode($params);

// too much work to put in this example
$charset = ...; //do some magic with $mime->parts to get the character set
$text = ...; //do some magic with $mime->parts to get the text

// fix the =A0 control character; it's already been decoded 
// by Mail_Mime, so we need the actual byte code now
// this has to be done before trying to convert to UTF-8
$char = chr(hexdec(substr('A0',1)));
$text = str_replace($char, '', $text);

// convert to UTF-8 using ConvertCharset
require 'ConvertCharset.class.php';
if( strtolower($charset) != 'utf-8' ) {
  $converter = new ConvertCharset($charset, 'utf-8', false);
}
$text = $converter->Convert($text);
```

Then everything is spiffy. It even does the infamous Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn conversion, as well as accepting french, spanish, and pastes directly from MS Word :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to do it by the spec's which is I'm afraid to pull in the 'Content-Type' mime header, pick up the charset (it'll look like `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"`) then convert to UTF-8, and of course ensure your output on the web is sent as UTF-8 with the right headers.

Comment: Mail_Mime library already pulls in the charset and converts it accordingly. Some symbols, most notably ones copied from Word, still get munged. This isn't a problem of not understanding what to do, it's a problem of them not obeying the charset they claim to be sending.